# C++ fmtlib: "Undefined reference" error after building and #include <> this library

Tags: c++, include, fmt

I downloaded the library from https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt and then executed the following commands from official documentation https://fmt.dev/latest/usage.html:

```sh
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
sudo make install
```

The commands were executed without errors. The final output of the `sudo make install` command:

```
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: "Release"
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/libfmt.a
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/fmt/args.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/fmt/chrono.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/fmt/color.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/fmt/compile.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/fmt/core.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/fmt/format.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/fmt/format-inl.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/fmt/locale.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/fmt/os.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/fmt/ostream.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/fmt/printf.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/fmt/ranges.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/fmt/xchar.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/cmake/fmt/fmt-config.cmake
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/cmake/fmt/fmt-config-version.cmake
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/cmake/fmt/fmt-targets.cmake
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/cmake/fmt/fmt-targets-release.cmake
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/fmt.pc
```

I next created the file `main.cpp` with the following content:

```cpp
#include <fmt/core.h>

int main()
{
    fmt::print("Hello");

    return 0;
}
```

And compiled it with the command `g++ main.cpp -o main`.
However, the compilation results in the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccJ3FzHH.o: in the function «main»:
main.cpp:(.text+0x8a): undefined reference to «fmt::v8::vprint(fmt::v8::basic_string_view<char>, fmt::v8::basic_format_args<fmt::v8::basic_format_context<fmt::v8::appender, char> >)»
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am using Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Did you link it? add `-lfmt`

Comment: `g++ main.cpp -lfmt -o main`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the argument `-lfmt` to the compilation command solves the issue.
`-l<name>` arguments generally stand for including the library `<name>` into the compilation (see [GCC documentation](https://www.rapidtables.com/code/linux/gcc/gcc-l.html))

The command thus looks as follows:

```sh
$ g++ main.cpp -lfmt -o main
```